# Ionic 2 side menu after login

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I m making an app with ionic 2 ,so when app opens it loads login first, after login successfull home page with side menu template will open.I m not getting it ,So any help plz?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you having trouble navigating to your home page after the user hits submit? Look at NavController docs if that is the case

Comment: after user login it should open home template with side menu and it not coming

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
})

export class DashboardPage {    
  constructor(public menu: MenuController) {
    this.menu.enable(true, 'sidenav'); //'sidenav' is id of my <ion-menu>
    this.menu.open();
  }     
}
```

Comment: can you please help me in ionic 2 issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706137/ionic-2-side-menu-and-tab-is-not-working-after-i-redirect-from-login-screen